# Ajax toolkit issue with file name (illegal character in file name)

Tags: asp.net, ajaxcontroltoolkit

here is some strange issue, windows systems are not allowed to include pipe (|) sign in the file name while mac os allowed that. now when I upload the file from the mac system with the pipe sign in the file name it is throwing me errors like illegal characters in the file name(Illegal characters in path.)
so it looks like the issue is when we upload files in the windows system it is not allowing the pipe sign. so resolve that I have tried to change the file name before upload and for that i have tried OnClientUploadStarted function but it never its the function.

```
<aspa:AjaxFileUpload ID="AFUMedia" CssClass="AjaxFileUpload" runat="server" AllowedFileTypes="mpeg,x-zip-compressed,mp3,zip" MaximumNumberOfFiles="10" OnUploadComplete="AFUMedia_UploadComplete" OnClientUploadComplete="uploadComplete" OnClientUploadStarted="uploadstarted" OnClientUploadError="uploadstarted"  Width="523px" UseAbsoluteHandlerPath="false" />
```

can any one please let me know how to change the file name before uploading ?

Exception details

```
<Exceptions><Exception><Source>mscorlib</Source><ExceptionDetails>System.ArgumentException: Illegal characters in path.     at System.IO.Path.CheckInvalidPathChars(String path, Boolean checkAdditional)     at System.IO.Path.HasExtension(String path)     at AjaxControlToolkit.AjaxFileUploadHelper.Process(HttpContext context)     at AjaxControlToolkit.AjaxFileUploadHandler.ProcessRequest(HttpContext context)     at System.Web.HttpApplication.CallHandlerExecutionStep.System.Web.HttpApplication.IExecutionStep.Execute()     at System.Web.HttpApplication.ExecuteStepImpl(IExecutionStep step)     at System.Web.HttpApplication.ExecuteStep(IExecutionStep step, Boolean&amp; completedSynchronously)</ExceptionDetails><Message>Illegal characters in path.</Message></Exception></Exceptions>
```

Comment: Where do you get the error exactly? In your code behind?

Comment: it do not allow us to upload the file with pipe sign, you can try that in the mac systtem. and the issue i am getting is in the ajaxcontroltoolkit dll

Comment: @TheMixy added the exception details in the question

Answer (score 0):

You have to set/use the file name when you do the fileupload. saveas file. So, run a routine to clear/clean out the provided file name. You can't change/set the file name BEFORE up-loading, but your server side code when doing the complete "event" and "save as" for the file? You have the file name at that point in time in your code behind - and at that point in time you need to clean out the given file name string of funny characters.

Say like this:

```
Protected Sub AjaxFileUpload1_UploadComplete(sender As Object, e As AjaxControlToolkit.AjaxFileUploadEventArgs) Handles AjaxFileUpload1.UploadComplete


    Debug.Print("start of single file process file = " & e.FileName)

    Dim strCleanFile As String = TrimNonAscii(e.FileName)
    Dim strPhysicalPath = "some path name \" & strCleanFile

    AjaxFileUpLoad1.SaveAs(strPhysicalPath)

End Sub
```

and the trim function? Well, it can be this:

```
Public Function TrimNonAscii(ByVal value As String) As String

    Dim pattern As String = "[^ -~|]+"
    Dim reg_exp As Regex = New Regex(pattern)
    Return reg_exp.Replace(value, "")

End Function
```

So I strip out spaces, and a few others with that function.

You can't EVER mess or change the client side file name - for any browser and for any up-load. The reason of course is security. If you could mess/change the client side file name, then while you view cat videos on my site, then I would be up-loading and selecting files with my code - include Excel sheets called password, and documents say called "banking information". So the passed file name is what you get, and what you MUST deal with. You can't mess, nor change the provided file name - browsers don't allow this - as noted this is for reasons of security.

Given that you have to add path names, and often additonal information in that file name, then you have to simply generate your own file name - and if you going to use the passed filename, then you quite much need to clean it out of junk, and then use that.

Comment: I know we can change the file name in the code behind but the issue over here is that if you upload the file from the mac system with name including pipe sign in that, it will throw directly 500 error from the ajaxcontroltoolkit dll. so it is not going to hit the backend function of uploadcomplete

Comment: It should not toss an error. I allow mac users to upload all the time -  MOST certainly did see and get funny characters and even illegal  characters in that file name  (so added that clean up function).  Ajax file upload ONLY passes you the file name - it does NOT use it DURING up-load (that's temp storage). So bad file name during upload should not trigger or matter or cause an error. You have that ".save as" method of the uploader. Since we NOT yet saved the file, then the bad file name should not and does not matter. File name not used here during uploading and you don't either.

Comment: It is I supose possible that a file with a pipe character throws an errror. While I have many Mac users up-loading files - and we had some web exectuion errors occuring - and this WAS due to bad and funny characters in the file name - but the error ONLY triggered when I attempted the save-as - not during the up-load. So, I would 100% check and be sure it not the save-as that barfing out, or in fact that you never even get to the complete event, and thus can't execute the save-as with your file name of choice, or at the very least a cleaned out file name.